# Check login in FlowRouter in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, flow-router

I am using FlowRouter in Meteor.

On some pages, I want to check if the user is logged in, so I have made a triggerEnter function

```
const isAuthenticatedRedirect = ( context, redirect, stop ) => {
  if ( ! Meteor.loggingIn() && ! Meteor.userId() ) {
    FlowRouter.go( 'login' );
  }
};

const isAuthenticatedRoutes = FlowRouter.group( {
  name: 'isAuthenticated',
  triggersEnter: [ isAuthenticatedRedirect ]
} );
```

The problem is that it redirects the user to `/login` rather than just showing the login template.

I could make an if statement on all the pages, and then show the login instead of the real page if the user is not logged in, but I guess it would be way smarter to do it directly in the router.

Answer (score 0):

`FlowRouter` [does not allow](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router#rendering-and-layout-management) you to render the template, thus redirect is the only option. You need to install the other package to make it render directly instead of using `FlowRouter.go`